# MySQL Incorrect string value

Tags: sql, node.js, ubuntu

Я проверяю пользователя в базе данных, и если его нет, то отправляю запрос о создании его. Из за этого я получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x90\xD0\xBD\xD0\xBE...' for column 'userinfo' at row 1

(в столбце `userinfo` присутствуют русские символы.)
Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу заранее знать какие символы будут в запросе.
UTF8 стоит в базе данных.

ОС: Ubuntu 18.04 Server
UTF8.ru так-же установлен.

**UPDATE (перенесено из комментариев):**

```
+----------------------+-------------------+ 
| Variable_name        | Value             | 
+----------------------+-------------------+ 
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   | 
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci | 
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci | 
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Но после правки на UTF8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

проблема всё-же осталась.

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю заранее какие языки там будут использоваться. Что делать, если попадётся японский?

Comment: +----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+

Comment: Но после правки на UTF8 `https://i.imgur.com/zRLSBom.png`,
проблема всё-же осталась.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю заранее какие языки там будут использоваться. Что делать, если попадётся японский?

Comment: Если в это поле записать кириллицу, но короткое значение (символов менее 1/8 от длины поля) - что записывается в поле? корректно ли отображается на экране при обратном получении из БД?

Comment: Ошибка остаётся прежней, а в БД ничего не записывается.

Comment: Ну это понятно, что при ошибке запрос не выполняется. Т.е. если даже один-единственный кириллический символ в значении - всё равно ошибка? *Что делать, если попадётся японский?* Попробуйте сохранять как бинарные, а не текстовые, данные (и определить поле как BINARY/BLOB соответственно). Этому типу гарантированно до лампады любые кодировки - он пишет тупо байтовый поток. Ну а при обработке будете выполнять соотв. преобразования (ну и заранее почитайте мануал про coercibility, чтобы два раза не бегать).

Comment: Благодарю. Помогло.

Comment: Теперь не забудьте при любых операциях явно указывать COLLATE.

Answer (score 1):

Разработчики MySQL, по какой-то одной им известной причине, когда-то очень давно решили, что у них кодировка UTF8 будет означать "подмножество UTF8, умещающееся в три байта длины кода". Иными словами кодировка utf8 не поддерживает четырёхбайтовые символы из стандарта UTF8, которые есть во многих языках, и которые из себя представляют эмоджи. А потом, когда они поняли свою ошибку, им пришлось добавить отдельную кодировку utf8mb4 и соответствующие collation'ы.

В общем, нужно поменять encoding на utf8mb4 и collation, скорее всего, на utf8mb4_unicode_ci, если только вы не собираетесь сортировать строки на, например, японском языке, в котором несколько разных систем письма и с сортировкой всё сложно. Но с кириллицей проблем не будет. Как и с иероглифами, как и с эмоджи.